# How to set Switch size

Tags: qt, switch-statement, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I would like to resize a `Switch` (It doesn't matter if I use a`QtQuick 1.x` or `2.x`).

How ever, using parameters `width` and `height` doesn't work.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [customize the Switch to your needs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-switch) by providing a custom `indicator`.

By default this seems to be an `Item` with two children for the groove (`children[0]`) and the handle (`children[1]`). As you can't access those properties before the item is created, you could use a binding:

```
Switch {
    id: swch
    anchors.fill: parent

    Binding {
        target: swch.indicator
        property: 'width'
        value: swch.width
    }

    Binding {
        target: (swch.indicator ? swch.indicator.children[0] : null)
        property: 'width'
        value: swch.width
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that the binding approach assumes that the indicator has a child item, which might not be the case depending on which style is in use... although I think it would be very rare.

Comment: Yes, that is true, this only works for the default style. (*By default this seems to be an `Item` with two children...*) If you don't use the default style, breaking this style by providing a custom indicator still works.